# App crash when no internet connection

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask

so i was trying to create a simple login app connected to my wampserver by following tutorial on internet and it works fine, but the problem occurs when my device is not connected to internet and i can't figure it out why, but i'm pretty sure the problem is in my asynctask.
so i need help anyone, thanks.

here's my login.java

```
package id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.110:80/smkkimmanuel2/login.php";


    // JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String TAG_LEVEL_AKSES = "level_akses";
    private static final String TAG_JABATAN = "jabatan";

    public static String level_akses = "5", jabatan = "", namaUser = "";
    public static String login_status = "false";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // setup input fields
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        // setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        // register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Login.this.finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MenuUtama.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnLogin:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String levelaks, jabat;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

                    levelaks = json.getString(TAG_LEVEL_AKSES);
                    jabat = json.getString(TAG_JABATAN);

                    level_akses = levelaks;
                    jabatan = jabat;
                    namaUser = username;

                    login_status = "true";

                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MenuUtama.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


}
```

and here's my JSONParser.java :

```
package id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // Extract data from the response.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // Open an inputStream with the data content.
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
            String line = null;

            // Build the string until null.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Close the input stream.
            is.close();
            // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // Return the JSON Object.
        return jObj;

    }


    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

here's my crash report:

```
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861): Process: id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii, PID: 24861
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    at id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:138)
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    at id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-19 09:56:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24861):    ... 4 more
05-19 09:56:44.040: W/ActivityManager(571):   Force finishing activity id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii/.Login
05-19 09:56:44.050: E/IMGSRV(192): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 107
```

Comment: can you show your crash report?

Comment: catch (Exception e) try adding this to all ur exception handling code. and check what does the printstacktrace say?

Comment: @Modge i've added my crash report, please take a look, thanks.

Comment: @Mox you mean, to all exception in every class or just login class?

Comment: Do you know what a NullPointerException is?

Comment: @immibis yes i know it, but i don't know how to handle it, that's why i need help,

i know something is returning null but i can't figure it out where's the exact part that cause the problem, that's why i need help.

Comment: @WandaTeng you dereferenced null on line 138 of Login.java. What's line 138 of Login.java?

Comment: @immibis 138? it's a comment // json success tag

Comment: @WandaTeng then either that is not your actual code, or that is not your actual crash report, or the code you got the crash report from is not the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this is to use a [`ConnectivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to ascertain whether or not your device is online/has connectivity to the internet before attempting to do anything that requires a connection.

This way you can display a screen advising as such when offline, or attempt to run your code when online. From a user point of view this is favourable to your app just crashing when there is no connection available.

Comment: ok, i'll try this method, is this tutorial good http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/ to do?

Comment: Looks like a good place to start and once you've adapter it to your requirements you should avoid running into the `NullPointerException` when executing `makeHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is makeHttpRequest is returning null

```
// getting product details by making HTTP request
 JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
```

you can simply add an extra catch to your try/catch

```
catch (NullPointerException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Probably better practice is to check your connection with ConnectivityManager before you make the request

Comment: yup, it works, my app is not crashing, thanks @Modge, next i'll add the ConnectivityManager to complete it, i really appreciate it, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.110:80/smkkimmanuel2/login.php";`
 to 
`private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:80/smkkimmanuel2/login.php";`

The reason for this issue is that your IP is bound to that connection and when you are not connected then it's not your IP anymore.

Comment: well i'm not sure about this, cause i'm debugging the app using my android device, and if i change it to localhost, it won't work

Comment: I did a little change. Try now.

Comment: still same, i can't connect to mysql in wampserver if i'm not using my local IP.
cause i'm not using android emulator so it won't work, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to to avoid crash is just check the device if it is connected to the internet.

```
*ifConnected * : Do your process
*ifNotConnected *: Then display a dialog box to user that he/she is not connected to the internet.
```

This is what I do in the development.
This might help you :-

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
 }
```

You need to add

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved now, thanks to @Karl and @Modge,

first, thanks to @Modge, to prevent the app from crashing, just add an catch exception in AttempLogin class, the doInBackground method which is inside Login.java, and it will keep showing the process dialog "Attempting to Login" :

```js
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // Check for success tag
   int success;
   String levelaks, jabat;
   String username = user.getText().toString();
   String password = pass.getText().toString();
   try {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    Log.d("request!", "starting");
    // getting product details by making HTTP request
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
      params);

    // check your log for json response
    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

    // json success tag
    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
    if (success == 1) {
     Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

     levelaks = json.getString(TAG_LEVEL_AKSES);
     jabat = json.getString(TAG_JABATAN);

     level_akses = levelaks;
     jabatan = jabat;
     namaUser = username;

     login_status = "true";

     Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MenuUtama.class);
     finish();
     startActivity(i);
     return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
    } else {
     Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
     return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

    }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }catch (NullPointerException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
                                      //THIS IS IT.
   }

   return null;
  }
```

and to complete the app, i add ConnectivityManager as suggested by @Karl, by following the tutorial here http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/. after creating the ConnectionDetector class, i tweak my Login class and it will be like this :

```js
package id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 private EditText user, pass;
 private Button mSubmit;
 
  //ADDED
 // flag for Internet connection status
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;  
    // Connection detector class
    ConnectionDetector cd;

 // Progress Dialog
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;

 // JSON parser class
 JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

 // php login script location:
 private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.110:80/smkkimmanuel2/login.php";


 // JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
 private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
 private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
 private static final String TAG_LEVEL_AKSES = "level_akses";
 private static final String TAG_JABATAN = "jabatan";

 public static String level_akses = "5", jabatan = "", namaUser = "";
 public static String login_status = "false";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

  // setup input fields
  user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
  pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
      
      //ADDED
  cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

  // setup buttons
  mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

  // register listeners
  mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  Login.this.finish();
  startActivity(new Intent(this, MenuUtama.class));
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.btnLogin:
   //ADDED
            // get Internet status
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

            // check for Internet status
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                // Internet Connection is Present
                // make HTTP requests
                showAlertDialog(Login.this, "Internet Connection",
                        "You have internet connection", true);

       /*new AttemptLogin().execute();*/
            } else {
                // Internet connection is not present
                // Ask user to connect to Internet
                showAlertDialog(Login.this, "No Internet Connection",
                        "You don't have internet connection.", false);
            }
   break;
  default:
   break;
  }
 }
 
  //ADDED
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
 
        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
 
        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
         
        // Setting alert dialog icon
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.failed);
 
        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
 
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

 class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

  /**
   * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
   * */
  boolean failure = false;

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
   pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
   pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
   pDialog.setCancelable(true);
   pDialog.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // Check for success tag
   int success;
   String levelaks, jabat;
   String username = user.getText().toString();
   String password = pass.getText().toString();
   try {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    Log.d("request!", "starting");
    // getting product details by making HTTP request
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
      params);

    // check your log for json response
    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

    // json success tag
    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
    if (success == 1) {
     Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

     levelaks = json.getString(TAG_LEVEL_AKSES);
     jabat = json.getString(TAG_JABATAN);

     level_akses = levelaks;
     jabatan = jabat;
     namaUser = username;

     login_status = "true";

     Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MenuUtama.class);
     finish();
     startActivity(i);
     return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
    } else {
     Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
     return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

    }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }catch (NullPointerException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return null;
  }
 }

 /**
  * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
  * **/
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
  // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
  pDialog.dismiss();
  if (file_url != null) {
   Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

 }
 

}
```

and it works like a charm, thanks for the help guys. I really appreciate it.

Comment: When i am insert two catch it says as remove that